# my solution for drag drop functionality is not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, drag-and-drop

I'm implementing simple drag and drop functionality into my website. It works fine as per drag and drop of image concerns. However, now I want to save dropped image into the server. For that I have included data regarding image in view as hidden elements, to access this data in jQuery I need dropped image id. I have tried getting this from following code it work's great in chrome but doesn't in firefox   please help  :

code:

```
 view <!-- dragable image -->
        <a href="#?w=976" rel="popup1" id="<?=$album['album_id'].'-'.$data->content_id?>" class="poplight album_photos"><img  id="<?=$album['album_id'].'-'.$data->content_id?>" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" alt="" src="<?=$imagePath?>"></a>
                                <input type="hidden" id="<?='wall'.$data->content_id?>" value="<?=$data->wall_id?>"/>
                                <input type="hidden" id="<?='type'.$data->content_id?>" value="<?=$data->content_type?>"/>
                                <input type="hidden" id="<?='user'.$data->content_id?>" value="<?=$_SESSION['user_type']?>"/> 

     <!-- dropable area --> 

<div class="" style="z-index: 1; position:fixed; right:124px; top:60px" id="div1" ondrop="drop(event);;" ondragover="allowDrop(event);"> <a href="#"><img id="dropzon_image"src="<?php echo IMAGE_PATH_HTTP?>babbler_btn.jpg" alt="" border="0" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand; "/></a><div id="overlay" style="display:none;z-index: 2;  position:fixed; right:0px; top:32px; cursor: pointer;border-color: blueviolet;"><img id="drop_image"src="<?php echo IMAGE_PATH_HTTP?>drop_image.jpg" alt="" border="1" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand; "/> </div></div>

/*js */
function allowDrop(ev)
    {    
            ev.preventDefault();

    }

function drag(ev)
    {      
            ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
               $("#div1").find("#overlay").slideDown();
               setTimeout( function(){$("#overlay").hide();} , 4000);

    }

function drop(ev)
    {     

         var id = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");/*implimented solution*/ 

         alert(id);


              ev.preventDefault();
             var action='download';
             var wall_id='62';
             var stat = 'Album';
             var cnt ='0';
             var user_type='R';
             var status = do_download(action,wall_id,stat,cnt,user_type);

         $("#overlay").hide();

           // ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
```

Comment: post HTML and JS to jsfiddle

Comment: hi i have change the question as i got solution to previous problem please refer changed one , and i dont no how to use js fiddle hence sorry for that inconvenience

Comment: hi here is js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rajutikale/CkY8z/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/TFv3a/

```
<a id="dragable" style="display:block;width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid red;">Drag here</a>

document.getElementById('dragable').ondragover = function(e){e.preventDefault();  }
document.getElementById('dragable').ondrop = function(e){ upload_drop(e); }


function upload_drop(e){
e.preventDefault();
alert('drag and drop works.');
}
```