# drag and drop working in chrome, not firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, drag-and-drop

Here's an example of drag&drop images (provided from course "HTML5 power workshop" by Andy Olsen) : 
http://aorbaroquethrash.com/dragdrop/

You have to drag an image from your desktop to the yellow square.

It is working in chrome, but not firefox, why ?

There's a similar post : 
[drag and drop not working in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18269677/drag-and-drop-not-working-in-firefox)
It says to use "dataTransfer.setData", but I don't think it applies to my example.

In my example I use 
`var allTheFiles = event.dataTransfer.files;`
...

PatricK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That site has a bug. The code reads:

```
// Handles drop events.
function onDrop(mouseEvent) {
...
    // Get the first file dragged by the user.
    var allTheFiles = event.dataTransfer.files;
    var firstFile = allTheFiles[0];
…
}
```

`event.dataTransfer.files` should be `mouseEvent.dataTransfer.files`.

The reason it works in Chrome is apparently that Chrome implement non-standard, IE-style `window.event`, while Firefox does not.

Here is [a corrected fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ctnpe/) that works (tested) in Firefox, Chrome, Safari and even IE10.